# Video Indexing to allow the upload 24hr of video in 1hr

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-cognitive-services

Trying to upload 24 hours of video in a batch of 1 hr all at once.

Tried to do it already but throttled back.

API call

Video could not be submitted.

Comment: In oreder to advice I need more info. How many files are you trying to upload? Video Indexer throttling configuration limits 1 upload every second (Just changed from 1 every 2 second). You should adjust your code to respect the retry-after header when response code is 429.

Comment: Yes, the 1 second change is what caused the error, they also changed the # of uploads to 30 per hour and eliminated the same video being processed twice. So, if I upload a 60m video every 3sec, then I will max out after just over a min.  Then they are queued one by one, so it might take 3hrs per video to process over 72hrs.  Does does that sound right?  or should it be based on 240GB@10GB each.  Either way the current capacity would be challenged.

Comment: There is no limitation of 30 per hour. There was a limitation of 30 per minute and now it is 1 per second which is a better ratio but has an impact on customer who tries to submit a large load in a very short time. The issue with indexing the same video twice is not new. It was done intentionally since many customers (by mistake) sent the same video multiple time. Regarding the speed of indexing / # of jobs in parallel. This is impacted by the configuration and Azure Media Service reserved units (max default is 10).

Comment: Throttling is now minute base. In Trial 30 R/M and paid 50 R/M

Comment: @Ika I'm trying to estimate now the time and space needed to analyze thousands of short (less than 5 minutes) videos. Is there any documentation regarding the performance and memory needed? Plus - any sample code of optimizing such parallel upload and analysis could be really helpful for me at this point.